# Testing interactive thor tasks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cucumber, thor

I have the following thor command:

```
require 'highline'
class Import < Thor

  desc "files", "Import files into the database"
  method_option "path", :required => true, :desc => "Path to folder containing new  files", :aliases => "-p", :type => :string

  def files
    require './config/environment'

    line = HighLine.new
    line.say(line.color("Identified files as Version 15 (English)", :green))
    if line.agree(line.color("Are you sure you want to import?", :yellow))
      line.say(line.color("Finished.  Imported 70,114 items", :green))
    else
      line.say(line.color("Aborting...", :red))
    end
  end

end
```

Now, obviously, at the moment this is just outputting some language to the screen.  However, what I need to do is write a test for the command that tests the output is as I would expect, and that when I start hooking in the heavy lifting that I can stub that stuff out.

I've had a look at [Aruba](https://github.com/cucumber/aruba), but this doesn't appear to like interactivity for some reason, and it's not clear why.

Therefore, does anyone have any ideas on how this might be testable (with RSpec)?

Answer (score 3):

Aruba is a pretty complete set of steps for testing command line apps. If it's not working for you it might be because aruba defaults all file operations into `tmp/aruba`.

But neimOo is right about how to write the scenario with aruba

```
When I run `thor import` interactively
And I type "yes"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can do this with Aruba

```
Scenario: Test import
  When I run `thor import` interactively
  And I type "yes"
  Then the stdout should contain "Finished.  Imported 70,114 items"
```

Here you can find a lot of aruba examples
https://github.com/cucumber/aruba/blob/master/features/interactive.feature

And here is implementation itself
https://github.com/cucumber/aruba/blob/master/lib/aruba/cucumber.rb

Comment: I think you can also require 'aruba/api' and use methods that implemented there
https://github.com/cucumber/aruba/blob/master/lib/aruba/api.rb
Even in RSpec

Comment: Won't this fail because there is not task import in tmp/aruba?

Comment: Thor script that Neil Middleton wrote will not fail, because it only write smth to output. So if i type yes, it will return what i expect.
But when we will have some file manipulation code, we can use relative path and everything should work